# Can I cancel the loading of a asp.net control inside an iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, gridview, datagrid, webusercontrol

I have an iframe on my page. Basically, the iframe hosts a user-defined control (let's call the control C). At Page_Load, this control C queries a database and displays the results in an ASP:DataGrid control

As of now, while the control C is loading its data and I try to navigate away from the page, the browser won't navigate to the new page until the data for the control C are loaded.

I wonder if there's a way to programmatically stop the the control C from finishing its loading process (something like the stop button on a browser)? I can stop the iframe from loading (i.e. trigger the iframe onload event before the control C finishin loading), but the brower still doesn't navigate away until the control C finishes loading its data.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there's a way to programmatically stop the the control C
>   from finishing its loading process (something like the stop button on
>   a browser)?

From the moment you ask for an other page, the control that make a long loop can only understand if the client is close his connection and must stop what he is doing by detecting that, and here is a code snippet for that.

```
    if (!Response.IsClientConnected){
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return;
    }
```

Now the only reason that your page is wait to finish what the previous action do, is the session lock that asp.net have by default and lock each request by the same user to keep a good synhronization. If you use the code to check if the use is still connected, I believe that you have what you ask.